# How do I optionally match future strings with regex?

Tags: regex, ruby, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regexp-replace

I have a regex, which I can make match if I explicitly match against the different parts of the string. But I need some of the parts of the string to be optional. Some parts of the string are recursive and can repeat:

Here is an example of a string: `[P1]<CX1>=AA1==B-1|R1|[P1]<CX2>-AB1-B2`

Let me break down the anatomy of that string a bit. It consists of these sections:

1. `[Something]`
2. `<something>`
3. `(#|%|=|-|\+)+[A-Z]*[0-9]*` -- This pattern can repeat with different permutations (e.g. `=A1-B2%2##Z` is three repeats of the pattern).
4. `\|` is a delimiter
5. `[A-Z]+[0-9]+`
6. `\|` another delimiter
7. Repeat steps 1-3 here

Step 4 and onwards are optional as a whole. So if step 4 is present then all of the steps (including repeating steps 1-3) must be present.

I have the following problems:

1. Matching the optionally repeating permutations in step 3
2. Matching everything from step 4 onwards given it's optional

So all of these are valid, and I would like a single regex to capture the groups in step 1, 2, 3 (each permutation), and 5:

```
[P1]<CX1>=A
[P1]<CX1>%A
[P1]<CX1>-99
[P1]<CX1>=A1-1
[P1]<CX1>=A1-1%C
[P1]<CX1>=A1-1%%C
[P1]<CX1>=A1-1%%C|R1|[P2]<CX1>=A1-23
[P1]<CX1>=A1-1%%C|R1|[P1]<CX2>=A1==B12-C
```

I would greatly appreciate any insights and help.

Thanks in advance!

Best,

PS: I'm using ruby's regex engine if that is important.

Comment: Not sure I completely understand but does this work for you? [Example](https://rubular.com/r/iHnFVRKHxjXVhI)

Comment: It is a bit long, but try `^(\[[^][]+\])(<[^<>]*>)([#%=+-][A-Z]*[0-9]*(?:[#%=+-][A-Z]*[0-9]*)*)(?:\|[A-Z]+[0-9]+\|(\[[^][]+\])(<[^<>]*>)([#%=+-][A-Z]*[0-9]*(?:[#%=+-][A-Z]*[0-9]*)*))?$`  https://regex101.com/r/bVD1cv/1

Comment: Readers: It has been reported that @Thefourthbird is so quick in responding because he/she uses dictation software.

Comment: ehhmmm.....wut?

Comment: If you want consecutive matches, so group 1, 2,3 and optionally group 5 `(?:(\[[^\]\[]+\])(<[^<>]*>)([#%=+-][A-Z]*[0-9]*(?:[#%=+-][A-Z]*[0-9]*)*)|\G(?!\A)\|([A-Z]+[0-9]+)\|)` https://regex101.com/r/MIiQo1/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird, thanks for concrete solutions! My online regex tool won't parse the first one ("Rubular suspects this regex will take forever to parse"). The second one looks right. I will do some work with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match group 1, 2, 3 and optionally group 5 you could make use of the `\G` anchor.

If there is a single string, you could start with `\G`:

```
\G(\[[^\]\[]+\])(<[^<>]*>)([#%=+-][A-Z]*[0-9]*(?:[#%=+-][A-Z]*[0-9]*)*)(?:\|([A-Z]+[0-9]+)\|)?
```

*Explanation*

- `\G` Assert position at the end of the previous match or at the start (in this case at the start)
- `(\[[^\]\[]+\])` Capture **group 1**, match from opening till closing square bracket
- `(<[^<>]*>)` Capture **group 2**, match from opening till closing angle bracket
- `(` Capture **group 3**

  - `[#%=+-][A-Z]*[0-9]*` Match any of the listed and optionally chars A-Z and digits 0-9
  - `(?:[#%=+-][A-Z]*[0-9]*)*` Optionally repeat the previous pattern
- `)` Close group
- `(?:\|([A-Z]+[0-9]+)\|)?` Optionally match Capture **group 4** between 2 pipes

[Regex demo](https://rubular.com/r/ntcW2XWCeuakeH)

If the matches do not have to be at the start of the string, you could use the anchor with an alternation `|\G(?!\A)` asserting it is not at the start of the string.

```
(?:(\[[^\]\[]+\])(<[^<>]*>)([#%=+-][A-Z]*[0-9]*(?:[#%=+-][A-Z]*[0-9]*)*)|\G(?!\A)\|([A-Z]+[0-9]+)\|)
```

[Regex demo](https://rubular.com/r/WEDGFhY3YudC9X)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. The strings that I gave as example was meant to be read as individual strings, not a multi-line text block. Sorry about that. 

Is it possible you can help me add the `\A` and `\z` delimiters to the regex to ensure that we don't parse multi-line strings?

Comment: The first example will only match from the start of the string. In the previous demo I added an optional newline to show all matches https://rubular.com/r/aVbNI6oWhZASSe